# white-space: nowrap is not working in IE in a horizontally scrolling box

Tags: css

I'm using `white-space: nowrap` combined with inline-block'd elements to create a horizontally scrolling box. For some reason, in IE, the `white-space: nowrap` is being ignored and items are wrapping.

Answer (score 27):

Found it! We were using `word-wrap: break-word` higher up. It seems that `word-wrap` interferes with `white-space` in Internet Explorer. Fix for this was to set `word-wrap: normal` on the element with `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only one that spends a couple of hours fighting something, finally posting a question then solve it 30 seconds later.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution!  I've spent all morning trying to fix it and this finally worked.

Comment: @Hawxby About one-third of my SO questions I immediately answer. Something about typing out the question effectively solves it.

Comment: Thanks! This also solves problems with Internet Explorer with Windows Phone 8.0 so that browser obviously shares the same source code for this part.