# CSS white-space: nowrap not working in IE

Tags: php, html, css, nowrap

Having a problem in IE with CSS nowrap in IE, works perfectly in Chrome. Can anyone help out so it renders without any wrapping in IE and Chrome?

HTML

```
<div id="sub_cont"></div>
```

CSS

```
#content{
height:14px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 450px;
padding-top:25px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#content #sub_cont{
width: 450px;
display:none;
height:14px;
}

#content .no-rec{
color:#000;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
padding:5px;
border-bottom:solid #000;
text-align:left;
background:#EBEBEB;
}

#content .each_rec {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBEBEB;
border-bottom: medium solid #000000;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding: 5px;
height:12px; 
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Search Result</h2>";
echo "<table border='0'  id='content' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='5'>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFCC'>
<th>VM Name</th>
<th>vCenter Name</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr class='each_rec'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['VM_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['VCENTER_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if($total==0){ echo '<div class="no-rec">No Record Found !</div>';}?>
```

Comment: See: http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/whitespace_1.htm

Comment: wich version of IE ? is there a valid doctype used ? ...

Comment: IE10 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer we must use the whiteSpace property in order to nowrap text, the documentation for the usage of whiteSpace is linked below. Good luck, and remember to use the most recent version of IE in order to maintain accuracy.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531182(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm trying to use in the #content style but it's not working in IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Reference url

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129006/1312610

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Try it for ie
    white-space: normal;

Comment: Tried white-space: normal in the CSS and it's not working in either.