# white-space: no-wrap in IE not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This works fine in chrome but IE doesn't like it and breaks the content-main div's.
Checked for `word-wrap: break-word` as noted here [white-space: nowrap is not working in IE in a horizontally scrolling box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129005/white-space-nowrap-is-not-working-in-ie-in-a-horizontally-scrolling-box/18129006#18129006) but I don't have that anywhere.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/02hgaahe/ although the fiddle in IE displays correctly.... odd.

Here's my code.

HTML-

```css
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : Jan 7, 2015, 2:31:39 PM
*/

body {
  font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
 }
        #wrapper {
  
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  padding:10px;
                height: 90%;
 }
        #header {
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  height:80px;
  padding:10px;
 }
        #header > #content-main{
            width:200px;
            height:80px;
            border: 1px solid #bbb;
        }
 .content {
            
  margin-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow-x: visible;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                height:320px;
 }
 .content div {
  border:1px solid #bbb;
 }
 .content-main {
            display: inline-block;
  width:500px;
                height:300px;
 }
 #footer {
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
 }
 #bottom {
  clear:both;
  text-align:right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">Header</div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-main">Left</div>
                <div class="content-main">main</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
                <div class="content-main">right</div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
        </div>
```

**Edit:** Removed duplicate ID's and incorrect comment.

It is still displaying incorrectly though.

**Edit:** I think the issue was with Internet Explorer's compatibility settings for intranet sites, I didn't know that IE defaulted all intranet sites to compatibility mode (basically IE7).

Comment: `//padding:10px;` isn't valid in CSS. Comments in CSS begin with `/*` and end in `*/`.

Comment: Please use classes, since multiple duplicate id's is wrong. So IE is telling you, "i've found a div with id content-main, and since id's are unique, i won't find another "

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: i think the problem here is more repeating id's, along with using IE.

Comment: @jbutler483 I didn't say that that was the problem.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Sorry, mis-read you comment. Still, your point is very much valid.

Comment: Thanks for catching those errors! It's still breaking and displaying differently than chrome though.

Comment: @Shadymilkman01: Please don't alter your code based on comments/answers, as SO should be left in the format of: here's a question, Here's an answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'll leave it alone in the future.

Comment: @Shadymilkman01 What `white-space` property is shown in the Computed Style panel of the Developer Tools? Also, which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @JonathanSampson when I select the content id it says white-space normal under computed. In the drop down for that it says #content- nowrap. I think you're on the right path... I'm using IE 11.0.9600

Answer (score 2):

Time for a shot in the dark!

Did you remember `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your HTML file? Without it, older IE versions will default to Quirks Mode, which may not behave properly when it comes to CSS.

Comment: Yes I did, yet still no cigar. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue here is that you're using repeating id's.

If you want to 'duplicate' the effects of one div onto another, try using a **class** instead.

Using classes makes the 'class' reusable, unlike using 'id's, which **should be** unique and **not repeated**. Duplicating ID's cause all sorts of funny bugs/glitches.

Something like:

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 90%;
}
#header {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#header > #content-main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
#content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 320px;
}
#content div {
  /*padding:10px;*/
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.content-main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
#footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
#bottom {
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-main">Left</div>
    <div class="content-main">main</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
    <div class="content-main">right</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

---

As a side note, as @James said, comments in css look like `/*comment*/` and not `//comment`

Comment: if you're fiddle is displaying it correctly in ie, then there must be some other css acting on this. Could you check if there's other rules you've not included?